# Regex match the main expression only if certain length is given

Tags: regex

I am trying to match license plates which can only have a maximum of 8 characters in total. The regex should match both styles *M-MB 304* or *M MB 304* and ignore whitespaces. Additionally it should match partial plates (only `M` or `M-`).

So all words and digits except `-` should end up between 1 and 8 characters.

This is what I've come up with, it matches the correct groups, but I cannot get it to work with a length limit. I tried a positive lookahead at the start which should match all allowed signs, yet it doesn't work. It always matches plates with 9 or more characters and doesn't some with less.

```
^(?=(?:\w|\d|[^-]){1,8})(?<city>[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,3})(?:-(?<letters>[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,2}) ?(?<numbers>[1-9]{1}([0-9]{1,3})*))?$
```

These should match or not:

```
// Valid
R
R-
RM
RM-
RMG
RMG-
R-MA 233
R-MA 2333
R MB 2333

// Invalid
RMG-MA2033
MGD-MB 2332
```

Comment: Please instead of voting closes explain what details you need or don't understand. How should I improve my questions if all are giving silent feedback in form of close-votes?

Answer (score 1):

You might write the pattern as:

```
^(?=\w(?:[ -]?\w){0,7}-?$)(?<city>[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,3})(?:[- ](?<letters>[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,2}) ?(?<numbers>[1-9](?:[0-9]{1,3})*)?)?-?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\w(?:[ -]?\w){0,7}-?$)` Assert 8 word characters to the right with optional space or `-` in between and optional `-` at the end
- `(?<city>[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,3})` Capture group *city*, match 1-3 times any of the listed characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[- ]` Match either a space or `-`
  - `(?<letters>[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,2}) ?` Capture group *letters*, match 1 or 2 times any of the listed characters and an optional space
  - `(?<numbers>[1-9](?:[0-9]{1,3})*)?` Optional capture group *numbers*
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `-?` Match optional `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7lzpQv/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I thought curly braces are occurances, so shouldn't it be `{1,8}` or is it actually 0-based? Or is it because of the first `\w`? Why this and not just match up to 8 of the non-capturing group inside the lookahead?

Comment: @SharpShade The first `\w` is mandatory, then it is followed by `{0,7}` to account for `{1,8}` in total.